# Happstack handling

Tags: haskell, webforms, happstack

I'm parsing a form in happstack but I don't know of a more concise way to gather the form variables on the server.
Does anyone know if there are any tricks to reduce the amount of code needed here?

```
 formHandler = do
    method POST
    delA1       <- look "address-01-delivery"
    delA2       <- look "address-02-delivery"
    delSuburb   <- look "suburb-delivery"
    delPostcode <- look "postcode-delivery"
    delState    <- look "state-delivery"
    delCountry  <- look "country-delivery"

    bilA1       <- look "address-01-billing"
    bilA2       <- look "address-02-billing"
    bilSuburb   <- look "suburb-billing"
    bilPostcode <- look "postcode-billing"
    bilState    <- look "state-billing"
    bilCountry  <- look "country-billing"
```

Comment: `[a,b,c] <- mapM look [x,y,z]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Preface: This is clearly not going to reduce the amount of code that you posted above, but in the long run it may make things more maintainable as it provides a consistent way to perform validation and allows you to deal with strongly typed objects rather than large numbers of text values.*

If you are going to do any amount of form processing, I would recommend using a forms library. I've personally used [digestive-functors](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/digestive-functors) and have found it enjoyable to work with. As well, it comes with a Happstack backend which makes the Happstack integration very straight-forward.

This may be more than you care to invest in, but here is a sample of what your form code might look like using digestive functors. I didn't try compiling any of this, so it may or may not work, but hopefully it provides the general idea.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Forms where

import Control.Applicative ((<$>), (<*>))
import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Happstack.Server
import Text.Digestive


data AddressState 
  = Alabama
  | Alaska
  | Arkansas
  -- ...
  deriving (Enum, Eq, Read)

data Country
  = Canada
  | Mexico
  | UnitedStates
  -- ...
  deriving (Enum, Eq, Read)

data Address = Address
  { street1  :: Text
  , street2  :: Maybe Text
  , suburb   :: Maybe Text
  , postcode :: Int
  , state    :: AddressState
  , country  :: Country
  }

data ShippingForm = ShippingForm
  { deliveryAddress :: Address
  , billingAddress  :: Address
  }

addressForm :: (Monad m) => Form Text m Address
addressForm = Address
  <$> "street1"  .: nonEmptyText (text Nothing)
  <*> "street2"  .: optionalText Nothing
  <*> "suburb"   .: optionalText Nothing
  <*> "postcode" .: stringRead "Please enter a valid postcode" Nothing
  <*> "state"    .: choice mkChoices Nothing
  <*> "country"  .: choice mkChoices Nothing
  where
    nonEmptyText = check "Cannot be empty" (not . T.null)
    mkChoices = [(x, T.pack (show x)) | x <- [minBound .. maxBound]]

shippingForm :: (Monad m) => Form Text m ShippingForm
shippingForm = ShippingForm
  <$> "delivery" .: addressForm
  <*> "billing"  .: addressForm

formHandler :: ServerPart Response
formHandler = do
  method POST
  decodeBody $ defaultBodyPolicy "/tmp" 4096 4096 4096
  res <- runForm "shipping" shippingForm
  case res of
    (view, Nothing) -> do
      -- setup your view
      ok $ toResponse () -- <-- replace this with your view code
    (_, Just formData) -> do
      -- here, formData is a fully valid `ShippingForm`
      let delStreet1 = (street1 . deliveryAddress) formData
      -- do whatever you need to with this data (ie: persist it to a database, etc)
      ok $ toResponse ()
```

For some good reading on digestive functors, you could check out the following links:

[digestive functors tutorial](https://github.com/jaspervdj/digestive-functors/blob/master/examples/tutorial.lhs)

[ocharles' blog post](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2012-12-02-digestive-functors.html)